# How to set default date as 1 of month in datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/. I am trying to set default day as 1 of month.

```
<script>
var firstDayOfMonth = function() {
    // your special logic...
    return 1;
};

var d = new Date();
var currMonth = d.getMonth();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();
var startDate = new Date(currYear,currMonth,firstDayOfMonth());
console.log(startDate);
$('#dp1').datepicker('setDate',startDate);
</script>
```

But it doesnt work as expected.Instead it comes with today's date.What i am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No.I am getting "Fri Apr 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)".

Comment: Check my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bikashm/1x7uvz2f/). It works here. Have you included necessary scripts and css?

Comment: Yes.It is working fine for me in fiddle.                                             http://jsfiddle.net/JBh3x/5/      But it doesnt work for me in code.

Comment: Okay. Can you confirm if you've included bootstrap.css, jquery.js and bootstrap-datepicker.js in your page?

Comment: I am using http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: Did you import first JQuery.js, then bootstrap.js and `eyecoon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker` at last ??

Comment: yes.I have included.